# Are the phrases “at once” and “in one go” equally acceptable?

Tags: meaning

You should answer this question *in one go* ( *at once* ).

Are both forms acceptable?

Comment: "in one go" does not mean the same thing as "at once"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"At once" means *immediately*. I assume you mean "all at once". Yes, both *all at once* and *in one go* are acceptable and mean similar things, but they are different. "All at once" means *simultaneously* (so the described action must involve multiple objects), or else *suddenly*, while "in one go" means the object (not necessarily multiple) was accomplished in a single action (not necessarily suddenly).

Also, *in one go* is more British than American. Google Ngrams reports that the phrase comprises roughly 0.000027% of text in [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20one%20go&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20one%20go%3B%2Cc0https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20one%20go&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20one%20go%3B%2Cc0), but only 0.000006% in [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20one%20go&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20one%20go%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Yes, I meant " all at once ".
I have learned American Language many years ago and never heard " in one go " till today.
T hank you for your explanation.

Comment: @Ahmetyılmaz You're welcome! If you're satisfied with it, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left. (That shows others that it was helpful to you, and it awards points to each of us.)